# without for loop how can is show var type these value in TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have a scenario where i have a

```
var testVar=  list1.Intersect(list2);
```

testVar contains about 400 values.

Now i have to show all the value in the text box.
Like:

```
Textbox1.text = testVar...
```

So, without for loop how can is show these value in TextBox

Please, Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are working with Lists of strings, you want to do this:

```
Textbox1.Text = String.Join(", ", testVar.Select(s => s).ToArray());
```

The reason I left the `s => s` lambda is that your list might not be of strings. So this construct will give you a chance to build your string items accordingly.

Comment: It's `Select`, not `select` (uppercase S).

Answer (score 7):

How about something like this:

```
string myText = String.Join(",", (from my in myList
                                  select my.ToString()).ToArray());
```

You might want to replace 'my.ToString()' with whatever makes the most sense given your object's type (or, if they are already strings, just select 'my')

Answer (score 2):

I am NOT saying this is the good way because I use the String.Join solution presented earlier BUT, for the sake of completeness and because I know most of us like to see how other people solve problems, a solution I've seen used is the Linq Aggregate() function.

```
    Dim laNumbers() As String = {"one", "two", "three"}
    Dim lsCSV = laNumbers.Aggregate(Function(s1, s2) s1 & ", " & s2)
    Console.WriteLine(lsCSV)
```

Comment: (I see that this was tagged C#, but the concept is simple enough I don't feel like rewriting.  Hope that's OK.)